# Как в проекте asp.net core создать папку, если она не существует, в директории на уровень выше директории самого проекта?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Как в проекте asp.net core создать папку, если она не существует, в директории на уровень выше директории самого проекта?

Я делал вот так, но это создает в директории внутри проекта

```
string rootPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string safePath;
            if (Directory.Exists(rootPath + "\\UploadedFiles"))
            {
               safePath = rootPath + "\\UploadedFiles";
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(rootPath + "\\UploadedFiles");
                safePath = rootPath + "\\UploadedFiles";
            }
```

Публикую проект на хостинге, в проекте есть функция, которая сохраняет изображение в папку, папка в директории проекта. Проблема в том, что при перезаливке проекта эта папка затирается. Я могу и в ручную создать директорию на хостинге, но как к ней путь прописать не знаю

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код, который вы попробовали написать, и уточните, что именно у вас не получилось.

Comment: что то типа `Directory.Create("~/../YourDirectory")`?

Comment: Вы хотите создать эту папку на машине разработчика? Или на сервере, где проект будет хоститься? А хост вам позволит?..

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, публикую проект на хостинге, в проекте есть функция, которая  сохраняет изображение в папку, папка в директории проекта. Проблема в том, что при перезаливке проекта эта папка затирается. Я могу и в ручную создать директорию на хостинге, но как к ней путь прописать не знаю

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir то, что вы написал в последнем комментарии, было бы замечательно добавить в вопрос

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, добавил

Comment: Гм, а эта папка включена в сам проект? В Solution Explorer?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да

Comment: Тогда почему она создаётся в коде?

Comment: В веб-проекте корень: `~`. От тильды отсчитываются все пути.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну я проверяю существует ли она или нет, если нет, то создаю. Мне бы вот как-нибудь на хостинге указать путь к папке, которая на том же уровне, что и папка проекта или на уровень выше

Comment: Это невозможно! Хостинг не позволит. Иначе любой мамкин хакер сможет влезть в папки и файлы чужого проекта на хосте.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а если я эту папку сам создам - руками, открою права, а из программы буду только писать в неё, это возможно?

Comment: На собственной машине можете творить что угодно. А на хосте доступ будет только к корню приложения. Выше - невозможно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а как же тогда хранить файла с данными, которые должны сохранятся и при перезаливке приложения?

Comment: Покажите, что-ли, скриншот Solution Explorer'а, где там эта злосчастная папка. / Перезаливка как осуществляется, с помощью чего? Возможно, при этом процессе не всё необходимое копируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть класс DirectoryInfo, в котором есть свойство Parent - оно указывает на родительский каталог, то есть на каталог, который находится выше вашего "safePath"

На экземпляре Parent можно вызвать метод CreateSubDirectory, если есть право на запись - в newFolder.FullName сможете увидеть полный путь к новой созданной папке:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(safePath);
DirectoryInfo newFolder = di.Parent.CreateSubdirectory("Имя Новой Папки");
```

Получить текущую директорию можно через Environment.CurrentDirectory